# NSNotificationCenter, blocks and ivar of type SEL: can't get it to work

Tags: objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying the following:

Whenever an OAuth token changes, I want to update some of my view controllers. The view controllers I want to update all inherit from a view controller. This view controller will listen for notifications whenever a new access token is set or whenever the access token is cleared. Whenever the access token is set or cleared, I want to set a selector to a method that should be executed once the view controller will be displayed (i.e. on `-viewWillAppear:`).

Somehow the blocks inside the `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` don't seem to get called. I can't get it to log even. Because of this the selectors never change. From what I've read using the `__block` attribute on an ivar should allow the ivar to be changed from within a block.

```
@interface SDViewController ()
- (void)reloadData;
- (void)clearData;
@end


@implementation SDViewController 
{
   __block SEL selectorOnViewWillAppear;
}

- (id)initWithDataSource:(id <SDViewControllerDataSource>)dataSource
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) 
   {
      selectorOnViewWillAppear = @selector(reloadData);
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   NSLog(@"view did load");

   [super viewDidLoad];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kAccessTokenChangedNotification object:self queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
      NSLog(@"selector: test1");
      selectorOnViewWillAppear = @selector(reloadData);
   }];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kAccessTokenClearedNotification object:self queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
      NSLog(@"selector: test2");
      selectorOnViewWillAppear = @selector(clearData);
   }];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   if (selectorOnViewWillAppear) 
      [self performSelector:selectorOnViewWillAppear];
}

- (void)reloadData
{
   NSLog(@"reloadData");
   selectorOnViewWillAppear = nil;
}

- (void)clearData 
{
   NSLog(@"clearData");
   selectorOnViewWillAppear = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Given the blocks are never processed, are you positive the code which fires the notifications is doing so appropriately?

Comment: It seems the notifications are not being called, but I can't figure out what would be the cause of this. I'm going to review the code a bit more ...

Comment: That's what I mean. Perhaps a good place to start would be where you actually post the notification (*as that's the other side of the equation*) and work forward from there. If you want to post that code here too, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: I think I found the issue. I'm adding an observer called self. It seems the block is confused about the 'self' part. Once I set the observer to nil, the code in the block is executed just fine. Since you've helped me figure out the cause of the issue, I'll give you a +1 :)

Comment: Thanks. This does make sense; according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-SW1) `obj` should be the object generating the notifications, not the one interested in receiving them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Fixed it by changing the observer code from this:*

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
   addObserverForName:kAccessTokenClearedNotification 
   object:self 
   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] 
   usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
      NSLog(@"selector: test2");
      selectorOnViewWillAppear = @selector(clearData);
   }];
```

*To this:*

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
   addObserverForName:kAccessTokenClearedNotification 
   object:nil 
   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] 
   usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
      NSLog(@"selector: test2");
      selectorOnViewWillAppear = @selector(clearData);
   }];
```

The Apple documentation related to this issue [is found here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000219-SW1). The object in the 
`-addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` method should be the object that generates the notifications. Setting the object to `nil` fixed the issue.